# If $W$ is a proper closed subset of $V$, then $W$ correspondes to a prime ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

> Let $V$ be a $k$-variety $1$-dimensional. If $W$ is a proper closed subset of $V$, then $W$ correspondes to a prime ideal?

I saw this statement being used in a demonstration, but I couldn't prove it. Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's wrong. The ideal will be prime iff $W$ is a reduced point, so for example two points give a non-prime ideal.

Comment: In this case, $V$ is a subset on $k$-Zariski topology of $C^{n}$ with $C$ algebraically closed set, and $k$ is a field. This was used just to show that $W$ contains one point.

Comment: How do $C$ and $k$ relates ? Anyway what I said is always true : prime ideals in affine curves exactly corresponds to closed reduced points. An arbitrary closed subset of $V$ has no reason to corresponds to a prime ideal.

Comment: $C$ is an algebraically closed set containing a field $k$. Would you have any suggestions on how to show that any proper subset $W$ of $V$ is discrete? The objective is show that *any proper closed  subset of $V$ is finite*, but if I show that any proper closed irredutible subset of $V$ is a single point, I know how to conclude.

Comment: Do you mean that $C$ is an algebraic closure of $k$ ? Now, if $X \subset V$ is a proper, closed irreducible subset, it has to be the zero of some polynomial $f\in k[V]$. Since $\dim k[V] = 1$ (recall $V$ is a curve) we have $\dim k[V]/(f) = 0$ so it is a product of field. Since $X$ was irreducible $f$ is irreducible. In particular $k[X] \cong k$ so $X$ is a point.

Comment: Yes! Nice proof!